# Bath diverter spout has extra quarter turn left in it

Tags: leak, bathtub, spout

I've just installed (*screwed in*) a bath diverter spout. The outlet obviously has to point down once it is fully screwed in. When hand tightening,  it is possible to complete an extra quarter turn at the end to make it tight. At that point the outlet is pointing to the left.

I've applied Megaloc thread sealant to the male thread and screwed it in an left it pointing in the down direction as one would expect.

A few questions:

- Will the thread sealant be enough to ensure that this is not going to leak?
- How long do I need to wait for the thread sealant to cure/dry?
- How will I be able to tell if this is leaking back into the wall?

The image from under the spout shows a hole at the bottom flush with the wall.

- Is this to drain the water onto the outside of the wall instead of the inside if there were a leak?

[image]

[image]

Comment: **More info on how this is set up**. Does the spout have a fitting inside that excepts  a threaded fitting on a pipe protruding from the wall? Did you use teflon tape?  Please give us a detailed description of how the spout connects to the plumbing in the wall.

Comment: @AlaskaMan - there is a pipe protruding from the wall with a male thread. It's about three-quarters the length of the spout. I put megaloc sealant on the male thread but no teflon tape.

Comment: That same faucet comes in a slip fit that uses a set screw to hold in place. There should not be water in there.

Comment: @EdBeal - this one is a threaded NPT spout and not a slip-fit one. Thanks.

Comment: Guy I fully understand that but don’t you think they use the same mold with minor changes to increase their profit margin? The mold for casting is the expensive part. When I was building track homes we would get special buys of the same spigot shell with screw on or slip on fittings, and in different finishes. So I understand yours is screw on but it is not hard with the fitting that has a o ring and set screw to turn this into a slip on. My dad did not like the slip on fittings they were new prior to his death but we unscrewed them and fit them with with copper.